# to call method in viewdidload method

Tags: iphone

I am trying to create application that gives customer information through web service. I have write the code in `appdelgate` class for parsing. How to call this method in `rootviewcontroller` class in `viewdidload` method ? Here is my code:

```
- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(UIApplication *)application 
{   

    NSURL *url = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:@"http://192.168.0.218:84/WebServiceCustomerByAmit/Service.asmx/GetWholeCustomerInformation"];
    NSXMLParser *xmlParser = [[NSXMLParser alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url];
    //Initialize the delegate.
    XMLParser *parser = [[XMLParser alloc] initXMLParser];
    //Set delegate
    [xmlParser setDelegate:parser];
    //Start parsing the XML file.
    BOOL success = [xmlParser parse];
    if(success)
        NSLog(@"No Errors");
    else
        NSLog(@"Error Error Error!!!");
    [window addSubview:[navigationController view]];
    [window makeKeyAndVisible];
    [navigationController release];
}
```

Comment: You want to call parser from other class ???

Comment: You can create parser in the class in witch you want to call it !!!

Comment: actually i have written so many classes that reference to (UIApplication *)application. I was thinking directly i call this method in viewdidload method then there will be no need to modify classes

Comment: What method you want to call ???

Comment: applicationDidFininshLAunching- method

Comment: You cant call this method because it calls once when application Finish lunching.

Comment: ok!! thanks.. i was trying to call it but unable ..offcourse u r right!! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create parser in the class in witch you want to use it ... Or you can create Parser in one class and from another call it and gave the delegate of the class witch you want ...